# NullPointerException when trying to pass connection object to another java class

Tags: java

I have a java class which establishs database connection using properties file. For insertion data to tables, I have written another java class which gets the connection object from the first class.

Here is the connection class

```
package feedback;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class DbConnection {

private static String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/online_feedback";
public static Connection con;
static String properties[] = new String[2];


public static Connection connectDB() {
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, properties[0], properties[1]);
        System.out.println("Conn obj :::" + con);
        System.out.println(properties[0]);
        System.out.println(properties[1]);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DbConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DbConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return con;

}

public void loadProp() {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("connection.properties");
    try {
        prop.load(input);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DbConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println("exception " + ex);
    }

    String username = prop.getProperty("username");
    String password = prop.getProperty("password");

    properties[0] = username;
    properties[1] = password;

    System.out.println(properties[0]);
    System.out.println(properties[1]);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    DbConnection d = new DbConnection();
    d.loadProp();
    Connection cont = d.connectDB();
    System.out.println("okay " + cont);

}

}
```

This class works fine when debugging. It prints username, password as well as the connection object.

Here's the second class

```
package feedback;

import java.sql.Connection;

public class Test {


   public static void main (String[] args){
        Connection c = DbConnection.connectDB();
        System.out.println("connected " + c);
   }
}
```

problem is it prints null as the connection object.

Please help me to figure out what has gone wrong

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check your logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get `null` because your `Test` calls `DbConnection.connectDB();` before making a call to `loadProp()`. You can fix this problem if you copy the first two lines from the `main` into your code.

However, this would not be a good fix, because you have a non-static method `loadProp()` that modifies `static String properties[]` array.

You would be better off making `loadProp()` static. In order to do that you would have to replace `this.getClass()` with a static way of obtaining the class - for example, by using `DbConnection.class`. Moreover, you could convert the method to a static initializer, and avoid calling it explicitly altogether:

```
static {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = DbConnection.class.getResourceAsStream("connection.properties");
    try {
        prop.load(input);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DbConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println("exception " + ex);
    }

    String username = prop.getProperty("username");
    String password = prop.getProperty("password");

    properties[0] = username;
    properties[1] = password;

    System.out.println(properties[0]);
    System.out.println(properties[1]);
}
```

Now your new `main` would work properly.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly make your **loadProp()** static. Then do this:

```
DbConnection.loadProp();
Connection c = DbConnection.connectDB();
System.out.println("connected " + c);
```

The problem is your **loadProp** is an instance method. You will need to call it after constructing DbConnection to set the values. You could make it easier simply by making your **loadProp** static and call this before trying to get connection object. The bonus is that you don't need to make a constructor call.

Once you call the DbConnection.loadProp(), your static values are set and will be available for as long as the class is loaded. Therefore you can call it once in your application and get connection as many times as needed through connectDB. Calling loadProp once is sufficient and desirable (given your settings are not changing often) because reading through Stream is considered expensive and should be done only when needed.